# Does System.Array Really Implement ICollection?

Tags: c#, arrays, icollection

According to [MSDN docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.array.aspx), `System.Array` implements `ICollection`, yet `System.Array` does not provide a `Count` property (of course you can always use the LINQ `Count()` extension method, but there is no property with this name). How can this be? Isn't `Count` required?

Comment: Yes, here's your `Count` property: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb357392.aspx Why it's explicitly implemented instead of implicitly is a question for the framework designers

Comment: `((ICollection)theArray).Count`

Comment: Yes, for example, you can call `Add` (defined in `ICollection`) on the array and get an exception.

Comment: @MattBurland explicitly implemented due to DRY I imagine. `Array` already has `Length` and the explicit `Count` just returns `Length` for that interface. Having `Length` and `Count` on the same class doing the same thing would be silly.

Comment: @Matthew: You are confusing `System.Collection.ICollection` with `System.Collection.Generic.ICollection`. The `ICollection` interface doesn't have an `Add` method. `ICollection<T>` does, but that wasn't the question.

Comment: @DavidHaney: Probably true. Although it's not so much DRY as hiding the fact that they are repeating themselves.

Comment: @MattBurland you're right, my mistake.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

It's [explicitly implemented](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/array.cs#693) like so:

```
int ICollection.Count
{
    get
    {
        return Length;
    }
}
```

You can read more about explicit interface implementation on [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173157.aspx).

Answer (score 4):

From [`Array.ICollection.Count Property` - MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb357392%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

> This member is an **explicit interface member** implementation. It can
> be used only when the `Array` instance is cast to a
> `System.Collections.ICollection` interface.

Answer (score 2):

From the documentation:

> Starting with the .NET Framework 2.0, the `Array` class implements the
> `System.Collections.Generic.IList<T>`,
> `System.Collections.Generic.ICollection<T>`, and
> `System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<T>` generic interfaces.
> The implementations are provided to arrays at run time, and therefore
> are not visible to the documentation build tools. As a result, the
> generic interfaces do not appear in the declaration syntax for the
> `Array` class, and there are no reference topics for interface members
> that are accessible only by casting an array to the generic interface
> type (explicit interface implementations). The key thing to be aware
> of when you cast an array to one of these interfaces is that members
> which add, insert, or remove elements throw `NotSupportedException`.

Comment: But the question is about [System.Collections.ICollections](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.icollection.aspx) not the generic [System.Collections.Generic.ICollection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/92t2ye13.aspx)

Comment: I see that now. Read the question a bit to hasty.